# How to efficiently read large datasets?

Tags: r

What is an easy way to read large data sets (~6 GB) in R without it hanging? Whenever, I read large data sets, R freezes.

Comment: Have you tried `fread` from "data.table"?  What else have you tried?

Comment: The only thing I have tried was splitting the excel file into smaller files(~ 50 MB each) and reading the sub files one at a time.

Comment: If the data are rectangular and the input is a text format (like CSV) then give `fread` a try. Is your source a binary Excel file?

Comment: Yes it is a binary excel file with ~20 columns. Hopefully fread won't crash R.

Comment: have you tried using an R-Studio AMI on AWS with an instance that has enough RAM & CPU power?

Answer (score 3):

If your data is in .xlsx or .xlsm files, you might want to consider the new [readxl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html) package that uses C libraries for parsing the XML structure inside of Excel files.

I believe it's now the fastest option available in R.

```
install.packages("readxl")
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("myfile.xlsx", sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE, na = "")
```

Comment: @lord12, this solution would be very fast, and I'm interested in the real performance. Could you report the speedup in this thread?

Answer (score 3):

check out the newest readr packages from Rstudio by hadley. [here](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/04/09/readr-0-1-0/)

It is claimed to be 10x faster and offers the same functions to load plain file datasets, e.g., read_csv read_delim read_tsv...

Another option is to use data.table package. It offers similar loading tools to be much faster than read.csv or read.delim.